# How to check whether I can send mail from my Linux server?

Tags: shell-script, mailx, mail-command

When I tried using mail or mailx with -r -s -a and other options, I am not able to send mail. Is there anything I need to check before sending mail from Linux server?

When I tried to see help for mail and mailx, I found below message:

```
[root@ukwcrbmorctd01 test_ezradsx]# mail --help
mail: illegal option -- -
Usage: mail -eiIUdEFntBDNHRV~ -T FILE -u USER -h hops -r address -s SUBJECT -a FILE -q FILE -f FILE -A ACCOUNT -b USERS -c USERS -S OPTION users
[root@ukwcrbmorctd01 test_ezradsx]# mailx --help
mailx: illegal option -- -
Usage: mailx -eiIUdEFntBDNHRV~ -T FILE -u USER -h hops -r address -s SUBJECT -a FILE -q FILE -f FILE -A ACCOUNT -b USERS -c USERS -S OPTION users "
```

Does the server I use support mail or mailx?

This is the log file.

```
Oct 11 12:12:53 abcpostfix/smtp[31869]: connect to abci1012.abc.net[10.209.205.31]:25: Connection timed out
Oct 11 12:12:53 abc01postfix/smtp[31869]: 2FC2D38A9C: to=<s.radhakrishnan@abc.com>, relay=none, delay=969, delays=939/0.06/3
```

Comment: What command do you use to send emails?

Comment: You will need to use something along the lines of echo "This is a test" | mailx -r "mrsender" -s "test" -a "testattachment.txt" somebody@somewhere.com

Comment: echo "Message_body" | mailx -s "test" s.radhakrishnan@abc.com and tried this command too. echo "Message_body" | mailx -r "d.dinesh@abc.com" -s "test" s.radhakrishnan@abc.com

Comment: There is no error while executing the command. But mail not received.

Comment: Do you check log files? See `/var/log/mail.log`

Comment: No. I checked just now. I found "Connection timed out" message and status = "deferred"

Comment: Does iptables enabled on your server? Can you append your question with log file data?

Comment: I have added my log file to the question.

Comment: I just checked mailq and found my mails are in queue with 'Connection time out' status.